# Default behavior for naming of columns for multiple merges... and changing it

Tags: r, data.table

I need to make merges across 5 taables, each with a common key, a number of columns with the same name, and a number of columns with unique names across each table.

What I've finding, is that the uniqueness of the column name breaks down after multiple table merges... what is the best way to deal with this issue, and force a unique column name?

```
library(data.table)
DT1<-data.table(IDs=c(1,1,2,3,4,10), V1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
DT2<-data.table(IDs=c(1,2,3,6,10), V2=c(6,7,8,9,10))
DT3<-data.table(IDs=c(3,4,7,8,10), V2=c(1,2,3,4,5))
DT4<-data.table(IDs=c(4,7,6,8,10), V2=c(10,11,12,13,14))
DT5<-data.table(IDs=c(4,7,6,8,10), V2=c(20,21,22,23,24))
tmp<-merge(DT1, DT2, by="IDs")
tmp
tmp<-merge(tmp, DT3, by="IDs")
tmp
tmp<-merge(tmp, DT4, by="IDs")
tmp
tmp<-merge(tmp, DT5, by="IDs")
tmp
```

Notice the handling if column names, and what happens in the last instance... I end up with duplicate column names, and when I attempt to access the value, I only get the first value.

```
> tmp
   IDs V1 V2
1:   1  1  6
2:   1  2  6
3:   2  3  7
4:   3  4  8
5:  10  6 10
> tmp<-merge(tmp, DT3, by="IDs")
> tmp
   IDs V1 V2.x V2.y
1:   3  4    8    1
2:  10  6   10    5
> tmp<-merge(tmp, DT4, by="IDs")
> tmp
   IDs V1 V2.x V2.y V2
1:  10  6   10    5 14
> tmp<-merge(tmp, DT5, by="IDs")
> tmp
   IDs V1 V2.x V2.y V2.x V2.y
1:  10  6   10    5   14   24
> tmp$V2.x
[1] 10
```

Comment: if you don't need to use `allow.cartesian=TRUE` (which I don't see in your example data) then you can join column by reference to your first dataset and assign the names to new columns. I'm quite busy to make an answer of it, but it goes like that: `DT1[DT2, new_col := i.V2][DT3, new_col2 := i.V2][...]`.

Comment: I need this to result in an inner join. If I follow your code, I think we get a a full outer join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table` allows duplicate names in general. It also mimics `merge.data.frame` behaviour in this case.

You can either use `make.unique()` on the names of merged result

```
setnames(tmp, make.unique(names(tmp)))
#   IDs V1 V2.x V2.y V2.x.1 V2.y.1
# 1  10  6   10    5     14     24

tmp$V2.x
# [1] 10
tmp$V2.y.1
# [1] 24
```

or use `Reduce` along with the `x[y]` syntax as follows

```
# requires 1.9.5+ for the `on=` syntax. Else you've to setkey() first
Reduce(function(x, y) x[y, on="IDs", nomatch=0L], mget(paste0("DT", 1:5)))
#    IDs V1 V2 i.V2 i.V2.1 i.V2.2
# 1:  10  6 10    5     14     24
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the duplicate problem. Is there an easy way to set the naming convention? In my case, I'd like to change each duplicate variable to have a naming scheme, such as V2.1, V2.2, V2.3, and V2.4

Comment: You can rename them to whatever you want. Check `?setnames`

Comment: yes, this is true - fair enough. I'm merging 300+ variables, so I was looking for was a method that changed the naming scheme/method of the merge function.. I don't like depending on an arbitrary naming convention (that ca change in the future, and thus break code), or hand-coding a bunch of renames.

Comment: i don't think it is possible unless we write a function to do recursive merge.